# Laravel: Table users has no column named updated_at

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-authorization, laravel-authentication

I changed the column name from 'updated_at' to 'last_updated_at' in the laravel 'users' table used for authentication.

Now I get this error during registration:

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 table accounts has no column named updated_at (SQL: insert into "accounts" ("username", "email_addr", "password", "updated_at", "created_at") values (...))

How do I make it use the new column name?

Comment: where did you change the name? in your migration?

Comment: probably need to change your model information, could you post the code for the related model and migration - thanks

Answer (score 10):

If you want to handle the field automatically and not let Laravel automatically manage `created_at` and `updated_at` fields, you need to set

```
public $timestamps = false
```

in your model.

If you want laravel to still manage it but keeping the new name, set

```
const UPDATED_AT = 'last_updated_at';
```

in your model

Comment: It's unclear why you would need to change the field name while using the laravel feature, however I edited the answer

Comment: I set "const UPDATED_AT = 'last_updated_at';" in my model and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `updated_at` column name by adding this to your `User` model.

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    const UPDATED_AT = 'last_updated_at';
}
```